# Can numbers displayed by utils::View be formatted?

Tags: r, formatting

Is there a way to control the number format when using R's `View()` function? I would like to limit the numerical output to something like `%4.2f` (when using sprint). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The function is called **V**iew() and the package is called {util**s**}.

Comment: Yes, I know. But, it is currently presenting 8 significant digits for all numbers. Can these be formatted to only 2 significant digits for the entire table that is presented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this:

```
X <- data.frame(a = c(921.131331,22.23523523, 3.5325), b = c(11.1435, 7.35, 8))

num.of.decimals <- 2
View(format(X, digits = num.of.decimals + 1))
```

Or:

```
X <- data.frame(a = c(921.131331,22.23523523, 3.5325), b = c(11.1435, 7.35, 8))

num.of.decimals <- 2

options(digits = num.of.decimals + 1)

View(X)
```